# Firebase Database doesnt write

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create "id, uid, and picname" branches in my realtime database but nothing does show. The rules are true for all.
Also nothing shows up in logcat. It's been bothering me a lot.

```java
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Logbook").push();
                            //Data will be saved in "Logbook" node.
                            Map<String, Object> updateMap = new HashMap<>();
                            updateMap.put("id", "");
                            updateMap.put("Uid", "");
                            updateMap.put("picName", "");

                            databaseReference.setValue(updateMap);


                            databaseReference.setValue(updateMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                                {
// Values Updated
                                 
                                    
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                                {
                                    Log.e("DB", "Error writing value", e);
                                }
                            });
```

Nothing happens in realtime database, in the firebase console

Dependencies list:

```java
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.0'
}
```

When debug, no "DB" nor "Error Writing Value" appears.

> I/oid.yoganetwor: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 25148(1390KB)
> AllocSpace objects, 8(224KB) LOS objects, 29% free, 3804KB/5376KB,
> paused 29.537ms total 318.674ms I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is
> not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
> I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too
> much work on its main thread. I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey!
> duration=1005ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=4214517390969,
> Vsync=4215117390945, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807,
> NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=4215132773200,
> AnimationStart=4215132813300, PerformTraversalsStart=4215134387500,
> DrawStart=4215451865300, SyncQueued=4215483849700,
> SyncStart=4215487366400, IssueDrawCommandsStart=4215487484500,
> SwapBuffers=4215489718900, FrameCompleted=4215526344700,
> DequeueBufferDuration=213900, QueueBufferDuration=702500,
> GpuCompleted=0,  I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2828
> bytes, containing 1 windows, 19 views W/System: Ignoring header
> X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. W/System: Ignoring
> header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. D/FirebaseAuth:
> Notifying id token listeners about user ( VkV7KzCLdjdLGFbjmDraGKFmNGt1
> ). D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user (
> VkV7KzCLdjdLGFbjmDraGKFmNGt1 ).

Comment: When you set breakpoints on all lines and step through the code in a debugger, does it ever reach the line with `setValue`? If so, does it go into `onSuccess`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it does reach `setValue()` but  then in `onFailure()` there is the log which I added in the edit. I don't know what happens.

Comment: That doesn't look like a stack trace. Can you `Log.e("DB", "Error writing value", e)` and include the output from tht?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen tried to Log the error, but still nothing shows up in Console nor Logcat. It is like everything is fine except that Firebase doesn't want to do anything. It is from this video and many users have the same issue, _[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3mcK5fUIns)_.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. The output you added does not include any stack trace though. If the code goes into `onFailure`, there's an error with a stack trace. Without seeing those, there's not much we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the error was not mine! It was google firebase realtime database' error.
 European database doesn't work for some reason, a special bucket is needed in google-services.json...
So, the solution is, when creating a database, choose whatever region except European.
This has been happening for almost two years now! I don't know how google lets this error pass.